# using TryGetValue from key and adding not working as intened

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, trygetvalue

I have this code to retrieve a value(integer array) out of a dictionary Then increment one of the elements inside the integer array based on the if statement it is in..

```
        Dictionary<string, int[]> ResultDic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
        if (TeamOnePoint > TeamTwoPoint)
        {
            ResultDic.TryGetValue(TeamOneResult, out OutOfDic);
            OutOfDic[0]++;
            OutOfDic[1]++;
            ////ResultDic.Remove(TeamOneResult);
            ////ResultDic.Add(TeamOneResult, OutOfDic);
            ResultDic[TeamOneResult] = OutOfDic;;
            ResultDic.TryGetValue(TeamTwoResult, out OutOfDic);
            OutOfDic[0]++;
            OutOfDic[2]++;
            ////ResultDic.Remove(TeamTwoResult);
            ////ResultDic.Add(TeamTwoResult, OutOfDic);
            ResultDic[TeamTwoResult] = OutOfDic;
            }
```

Now the problem I have is that evertime I read the modified OutOfDic array back into the dictionary into the value part where I specified the Key, every value in the dictionary is modified as well, and not just the key I specified.
The commented part gives the same result as the non commented part. How do I fix this problem to only add the value to the specified key?

Comment: _"read back into"_? You mean _write back into_? You're also incrementing two ints not one. Also, why do you use `TryGetValue` if you are sure that the key exists? You don't handle the case that a key is not present.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read the teams (Eg. 6 teams) into the key of the array and make the value (int[] TheArray) 0..  Then the teams play. and everytime a team play. (teamOne Win. TeamTwo Lost). then the teamOne P(Play) and W(Win) must increment. TeamTwo P and L(Lost) must increment. that is why I TryGetValue. I want to get the value of the team played and increment those values. then write(meant write) them to specified value where key == TeamOne

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you've described is only possible if you've added the same array to the dictionary multiple times. Since arrays are [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) every change will affect all values in the dictionay.

So instead of doing this(for example):

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> ResultDic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
ResultDic.Add("TeamOne", array);
ResultDic.Add("TeamTwo", array);
```

You should do this:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
ResultDic.Add("TeamOne", array);
array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
ResultDic.Add("TeamTwo", array);
```

Note that it's not necessary to re-assign the array to the dictionary for the same reason (it's a reference type). So you can remove these lines:

```
ResultDic[TeamOneResult] = OutOfDic;;
// ....
ResultDic[TeamTwoResult] = OutOfDic;
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that, for the same reason, setting the key-value to the modified array after modifying it is not necessary.